# Structure or algorithm optimized for store list/array in disk file?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

There are a lot of structures for storing tree/map to disk like B-Trees, or storing spatial data like R-Trees. Is there any structure for storing list/array to disk ?

Most importantly the add/delete function should not rewrite the whole file, and fast access for get/set the data is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

De facto, a B-Tree doesn't store any tree, but stores datas in a tree. If you want to store a list, use a list.
With a B-tree you can add/delete/get/set all the data, but if you insert or delete an element, the re-indexing is not made.

A solution could be a list that maps indexes to ids in the tree. Thus, when you add or delete an element, you just have to rewrite the indexes-to-ids list, and not the whole tree.

Answer (score 0):

Having to rewrite the whole file is mostly independent of the data structure. It depends on how you access your file. If you use streams, your only choice is to rewrite the file. On the other hand, if you use memory mapped access, you can change bits in a file freely.

Since a list / array is linear, you can easily calculate the position in a file assuming you have fixed size elements. Being able to directly seek to an element means O(1) read/write. The remaining problem is to size the file correctly since you can't append space that easily.

If elements aren't of fixed size you can take an approach like the FAT filesystem that keeps an index of where elements are. And if that's not elaborate enough you can look at other file systems. They are all in a way a `List<File>` storage.

http://vanillajava.blogspot.de/2011/12/using-memory-mapped-file-for-huge.html has a nice example of using mmapped files